# Exiting do-while loop with string input in java

Tags: java

I was trying to write the following code to allow continuous coin toss and exits when E is entered. Not sure if do-while loop is the correct way to do it continuously or i should use another method.

```
do {
    guess = sc.next();
    tossGenerator(guess);
    }while(!guess.equals("E")||!guess.equals("e"));
```

So, did I phrase the code wrongly because I can't get out of the do loop or a different method should be used. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Check out [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) - it helps with multiple negations etc.

Answer (score 8):

Change `&&` to `||`:

```
} while (!guess.equals("E") && !guess.equals("e"));
```

Or rearrange it like this:

```
} while (!(guess.equals("E") || guess.equals("e")));
```

Alternatively you can use [`String.equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) and eliminate the [conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction):

```
} while (!guess.equalsIgnoreCase("e"));
```

Comment: This requires `guess` to be initialized prior to the loop, which may be an additional change to the code.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to

```
while(!guess.equalsIgnoreCase("E") );
```

Answer (score 2):

The exit condition should be with AND operator:

```
!guess.equals("E") && !guess.equals("e")
```

otherwise any `"E"` or `"e"` would make trivially true at least one of them because if it's "e" then it's not "E" and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is that it will call `tossGenerator(guess)` even when `guess` is "e". Another is that `guess` is always going to be not "e" or not "E" (it can't be both at the same time). I'd write it like this:

```
guess = sc.next();
while (!"e".equalsIgnoreCase(guess)) {
    tossGenerator(guess);
    guess = sc.next();
}
```

Alternatively, use a `for` loop:

```
for (guess = sc.next(); !"e".equalsIgnoreCase(guess); guess = sc.next()) {
    tossGenerator(guess);
}
```